# Calculate GEOMEAN yearly, monthly and daily

Tags: excel, powerbi

I have this data:

```
COUNT   Date
197     10/2/2019
418     10/1/2019
58      9/30/2019
4       9/29/2019
7       9/28/2019
```

full data here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yvjrthe08jpdjmz/Data.xlsx?dl=0

What I need is a geometric mean yearly, monthly and daily. this image below answers that I need. I tried to follow it but still not work.

please any one can help me? thank you in advance.
[image]

I try the same instruction as the image above. But it still not work.

I do the same code like the image above.

this is the answer what I want:
[image]

Comment: Could you show your work? and give some more details on `But it still not work`

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego this is my power BI file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/e9eawagpz4srli9/Simple%20GeoMean.pbix?dl=0

Thank you.

Comment: I can not open pbix files from my excel, could you upload as xlsx?

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego pbix file run in power BI Desktop not run in excel.

this is link file excel work with Power BI:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1bhofpo6rda66c0/Data.zip?dl=0

Comment: I can not open any if your links. Anyhow, can you show any screenshot of your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer in the community.powerbi.com everyone can check link i attach below:

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-calculate-geomean-by-yearly-monthly-and-daily/m-p/808574/highlight/false#M388811